# Selenium webdriver script is not able to click any element after successfully login

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I tried all possible element locators but after successfully login the code is unalbe to click the element I want it to click. I get following error:

...

```
class charSequence {
    String str1="abcdef@gmail.com";
    String str2= "abcdfghhh";
    CharSequence cs1 = "int1";
    CharSequence cs2 = "int2";
    //boolean retval;
    public charSequence(String str){}   
}

public class QueuedRefund {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String[] temp1 = new String[1];
        String[] temp2 = new String[1];
        charSequence s1 = new charSequence("str1");
        charSequence s2 = new charSequence("str2");
        temp1[0]=s1.str1;
        temp2[0]=s2.str2;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/srvmedia/Geckodriver   /geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://dadfd.mywebsite.in/merchant/login");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(temp1);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(temp2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm")).submit();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a[1]/div")).click();

        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/a/div")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: So where is the error?

Comment: What element are you trying to click? You may need to wait for the element to appear / page to load before attempting to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your question says: after successfully login the code is unable to click the element I want it to click. and
(2) You have used "nosuchelementexception" tag.
Based on the these two facts, I gather you are getting error on this line:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a[1]/div")).click();

It will be helpful to understand the question and confirm my above assumption if you please post the error message.

Answer to your question depends on whether the element locator (xpath) you are using is correct or not. I am guessing the xpath is not correct because you are probably getting nosuchelementexception.

You can confirm whether the xpath is correct or not using FirePath add-on in Firefox browser. After installing it, enter the xpath in last tab named "Firepath" and press 'enter' key. The corresponding element (on which you want to click) should get highlighted. If it doesn't, then the xpath is not what it should be.

You can also check whether the element you want to click is in different frame on that page. In that case, you will need to switch to that frame first. Are there different frames on that page? You can use Firepath also to see this.

If you are sure (and you have verified using Firepath) that the xpath is correct, then check whether that element is enabled and displayed as per the source of that page.

```
Webelement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_that_element"));
System.out.println("The element is enabled: " + element.isEnabled());
System.out.println("The element is displayed: " + element.isDisplayed());
```

I am guessing at least one of the above two print statements will display 'false'.

If the xpath is correct and above two print statements display 'true', then try to print text on that WebElement (on which you want to click) using getText() method of WebElement. Does it succeed? I think it will not, because you are probably getting nosuchelementexception.

Please note: If the exception you are getting is not nosuchelementexception, you can remove that tag from the question.